# Local Save in Excel with iManage add-in

Tags: microsoft-excel

Using iManage (AKA Filesite, Worksite) 8.5 and Excel 2007. Having trouble saving documents locally. Saving into iManage works fine, but trying to export documents to a local directory using 'local save' triggers an error.

[image: Error #429 ActiveX component can't create object]

No 'save as' dialog is presented. Hitting ok on the error just returns the spreadsheet to focus. The add-ins are all enabled and local save works fine in word. Disabling the add-in allows users to save locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who encounters this issue. This was a version mismatch. iManage server was updated, but clients weren't.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check both Disabled Items and COM Add-ins. I've seen it show up in disabled items but also seen the COM add-in get unchecked. you'll have to launch excel using run as admin in order to re-check that box. then close, relaunch normally and try again. Other thought - be sure to check the registry for excel add-ins and the load behavior is not set to 2.

from Autonomy support page:

"an error occurred in the com-add-in name 'iManO2k'.
Error #429 
ActiveX component can't create object 
Location:[modOffice2000Common][ShowLocalFileSaveAsDlg]

Cause:
A shared resource, specifically, the scrrun.dll, has become unregistered or corrupted. Scrrun.dll is a system DLL that provides additional objects  for reading and writing text files in a file system.

Resolution:
Re-register the scrrun.dll.  To register a dll, go to Start | Run and type **regsvr32.exe [location of dll] scrrun.dll**

---

More from Autonomy Support:
just more of the same scrrun.dll and some long winded, best practices and other explanations of their dll's.

sorry can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. Got DLL "registered successfully", but didn't change the error.

Comment: They list some other solutions - will update my answer with a few other options from their support site soon.